# ¿Por qué me marca error SetSupportActionBar?

Tags: android-drawerlayout, xamarin.android

```
using Android.Support.Design.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.Widget;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Support.V4.Widget;
namespace KobitAndroidBeta
{
   [Activity(Label = "DrawerMenu")]
   public class DrawerMenu : Activity
   {
        DrawerLayout drawerLayout;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Menu);
            drawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

            // Init toolbar
            var toolbar = FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbar);
            SetSupportActionBar(toolbar); // AQUI ES EL ERROR, NO ENTIENDO PORQUE

            // Attach item selected handler to navigation view
            var navigationView = FindViewById<NavigationView>(Resource.Id.nav_view);
            navigationView.NavigationItemSelected += NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected; ;

            // Create ActionBarDrawerToggle button and add it to the toolbar
            var drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, Resource.String.open_drawer, Resource.String.close_drawer);
            drawerLayout.SetDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
            drawerToggle.SyncState();
       }

       private void NavigationView_NavigationItemSelected(object sender, NavigationView.NavigationItemSelectedEventArgs e)
       {
            switch (e.MenuItem.ItemId)
            {
                case (Resource.Id.nav_home):
                    // React on 'Home' selection
                    break;
                case (Resource.Id.nav_messages):
                    // React on 'Messages' selection
                    break;
                case (Resource.Id.nav_friends):
                    // React on 'Friends' selection
                    break;
                case (Resource.Id.nav_discussion):
                    // React on 'Discussion' selection
                    break;
            }

            // Close drawer
            drawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
        }
    }
}
```

Me aparece el error de  "SetSupportActionBar does not exist in the current context"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Segun la documentacion, [`SetSupportActionBar`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/toolbar/part-3-toolbar-compatibility/) pertenece a la clase [`AppCompatActivity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) no a `Activity`. Hereda de `AppCompatActivity` para poder tener acceso al metodo:

```
public class DrawerMenu : AppCompatActivity
{
  //...
}
```

Comment: Gracias, estoy nuevo en ésto de Xamarin, y apenas estoy entendiendo como funciona, se solucionó al heredar de la clase que mencionaste ;)

Answer (score -1):

necesitas importar esta librería para tener acceso a ese método solo que la compatibilidad con xamarin, esta es de android studio

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
```